# C strncat to my environment

Tags: c

So I got my go to split the environment path and I got them all

```
char *token;
char *path;
char copy[200];
char *search = ":";
char echo[] = "echo";
int main(){

    path= getenv("PATH");
    strncpy(copy,path,sizeof(copy)-1);

    token = strtok (copy,":");
    printf("%s\n",path);
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",token);
        token= strtok (NULL,":");
    }
}
```

I get want I need

```
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
/usr/NX/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/divms/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/space/befox/bin
/space/befox/bin
```

now I just need to concat a "/" to the end of all of those, and i got it to work BUT it only prints the 1st one.
so here is my code:

```
char *token;
char *path;
char copy[200];
char *search = ":";
char echo[] = "echo";
char *result;
int main(){

    path= getenv("PATH");
    strncpy(copy,path,sizeof(copy)-1);

    token = strtok (copy,":");
    printf("%s\n",path);
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        result = strncat (token,"/",sizeof(token+1));
        printf("%s\n",token);
        token= strtok (NULL,":");
    }
}
```

and now I just get:

```
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin/
```

What do I need to fix so I get all of the lines with a "/" at the end of them?

Comment: How do you know that the value of `$PATH` will fit in 200 bytes? After `path = getenv("PATH");`, I'd call `strlen(path)` and then allocate a buffer using `malloc`.

Comment: OP is doing nothing with `result` in `result = strncat (token,"/",sizeof(token+1));`.  Might OP want `printf("%s\n",result)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify the values that strtok returns. You're lengthening them by 1 char, which means you're writing past the end of a string, which is undefined behavior. In all likelihood, strtok replaces the `:` with a `\0` and saves a pointer to just past the `\0`, which should be the beginning of your second token. However, you replace that `\0` with a `/` and put a `\0` just past that point, and now when `strtok` goes to look for your next token, all it finds is that `\0` and it assumes your string is done.

Don't modify the return value from `strtok` without copying it first.

Comment: iv tryed copying it too, like having a *char copyt   then before the concat i id a copyt=token  still does the same thing

Comment: @user1547386: That's copying the pointer, not copying the string. You need to look at `malloc()` and `strcpy()`.

Comment: malloc is not strictly necessary, if you know for example that your tokens are all less than 200 characters long you could do `char temp[202];strncpy(temp, token, 200); temp[200] = '\0'; strncat(temp, "/", 2);`

Comment: @Dan: True, although you'd want to check each time, `strncpy()` with filenames in particular has the potential to lead to bad times. `sprintf()` is probably easier here than `strncpy()` followed by `strncat()`, too.

Answer (score 1):

I you just want to print, you might want to add the `/` in the format line:

```
printf("%s/\n",token);
```

You are getting only one line because you are modifying the buffer you are reading with the following line:

`strncat(token, "/", sizeof(token+1));`

As per documentation:

> Appends the first num characters of source to destination, plus a terminating null-character.

You should copy the token and then add the trailing `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't attempt to modify the string you're passing to `strtok()`, you'll get highly unexpected behavior that way. You should set up a new string and copy the string pointed to by `token` to it, and do the concatenation there. `sizeof(token+1)` is also incorrect, both because you're just adding `1` to the pointer and not affecting the result of `sizeof` at all, and because you're just getting the size of the pointer this way. `strlen()` is what you're looking for.